# OrientDB: Trouble creating distributed clusters with hotalignment=true

Tags: orientdb

I are using OrientDB 2.1.7 in embedded and distributed mode, and the application is running on two nodes (two Java processes).

When using the default JSON database configuration, everything works fine:

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "hotAlignment": false,
  "executionMode": "undefined",
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": 2,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum": false,
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
      "replication": false
    },
    "index": {
      "replication": false
    },
    "*": {
      "servers": ["<NEW_NODE>"]
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want to change hotAlignment to "true", but when I do this, I get the following error when starting node 2 (note: the database is not deployed to node 2 at this point, but it has been created on node 1):

> 2015-12-17 16:28:32:010 INFO  [order2] Saving distributed configuration file for database 'test' to: ./databases/test/distributed-config.json [OHazelcastPlugin]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:32:012 INFO  [order2] received new status order2.test=ONLINE [OHazelcastPlugin]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:32:019 INFO  [order2] found no previous messages in queue orientdb.node.order2.test.request [OHazelcastDistributedMessageService]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:32:043 INFO  [order2] Publishing online status for database order2.test... [OHazelcastDistributedDatabase]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:32:046 INFO  [order2] received updated status order2.test=ONLINE [OHazelcastPlugin]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:32:052 INFO  [order2] class 'ORole', creation of new local cluster 'orole_order2' (id=-1) [OHazelcastPlugin]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:32:134 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 0/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:32:522 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 1/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:32:903 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 2/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:33:283 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 3/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:33:663 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 4/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:34:043 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 5/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:34:419 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 6/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:34:799 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 7/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:35:176 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 8/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:35:556 WARNI Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: ids are different (local=9 and remote=15). Retrying 9/10... [ODistributedStorage]
>   2015-12-17 16:28:35:910 SEVER [order2] error on creating cluster 'orole_order2' in class 'ORole':  [OHazelcastPlugin][order2] Error on starting distributed plugin
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Error on creating cluster 'orole_order2' in class 'ORole'
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installLocalClusterPerClass(OHazelcastPlugin.java:1624)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installDbClustersForLocalNode(OHazelcastPlugin.java:1293)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.loadDistributedDatabases(OHazelcastPlugin.java:1434)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.startup(OHazelcastPlugin.java:187)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.registerPlugins(OServer.java:979)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer.activate(OServer.java:346)
>       at no.kommune.bergen.graftest.GraphDBServerWrapper.startDatabaseServer(GraphDBServerWrapper.java:74)
>       at no.kommune.bergen.graftest.GraftestApplication.main(GraftestApplication.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Error on creating cluster on distributed nodes: local and remote ids assigned are different
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedStorage.addCluster(ODistributedStorage.java:1364)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.addCluster(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1291)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.createClusterIfNeeded(OClassImpl.java:2102)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClassImpl.addCluster(OClassImpl.java:1068)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.installLocalClusterPerClass(OHazelcastPlugin.java:1617)
>       ... 13 more

It seems to have trouble creating local clusters for node2 when turning on hotAlignment. I have also seen the same problem when turning off autodeploy. 
Is there something missing from my configuration?

EDIT: This is how we start the server:

```
    OServerConfiguration cfg = new OServerConfiguration();
    //DB server config
    cfg.handlers = new ArrayList<OServerHandlerConfiguration>();
    //Cluster plugin config
    OServerHandlerConfiguration hazelcastHandlerConfig = new OServerHandlerConfiguration();
    hazelcastHandlerConfig.clazz = "com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin";
    hazelcastHandlerConfig.parameters = new OServerParameterConfiguration[6];
    hazelcastHandlerConfig.parameters[0] = new OServerParameterConfiguration("nodeName", nodeName);
    hazelcastHandlerConfig.parameters[1] = new OServerParameterConfiguration("enabled", "true");
    hazelcastHandlerConfig.parameters[2] = new OServerParameterConfiguration("configuration.db.default", "/config/distributed-db-config.json");
    hazelcastHandlerConfig.parameters[3] = new OServerParameterConfiguration("configuration.hazelcast", "/config/hazelcast.xml");
    hazelcastHandlerConfig.parameters[4] = new OServerParameterConfiguration("conflict.resolver.impl", "com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.conflict.ODefaultReplicationConflictResolver");
    hazelcastHandlerConfig.parameters[5] = new OServerParameterConfiguration("sharding.strategy.round-robin", "com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.sharding.strategy.ORoundRobinPartitioninStrategy");
    cfg.handlers.add(hazelcastHandlerConfig);
    //Network config
    cfg.network = new OServerNetworkConfiguration();
    cfg.network.protocols = new ArrayList<OServerNetworkProtocolConfiguration>();
    cfg.network.protocols.add(new OServerNetworkProtocolConfiguration("binary", "com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary"));
    OServerNetworkListenerConfiguration binaryListenerCfg = new OServerNetworkListenerConfiguration();
    binaryListenerCfg.ipAddress = "0.0.0.0";
    binaryListenerCfg.portRange = "2424-2430";
    binaryListenerCfg.protocol = "binary";
    cfg.network.listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    cfg.network.listeners.add(binaryListenerCfg);

    //Storage config
    OServerStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new OServerStorageConfiguration();
    storageCfg.path = "plocal:./databases/test";
    storageCfg.name = "test";
    storageCfg.loadOnStartup = true;
    cfg.storages = new OServerStorageConfiguration[]{storageCfg};
    //User config
    OServerUserConfiguration userCfg = new OServerUserConfiguration(username, password, "*");
    cfg.users = new OServerUserConfiguration[]{userCfg};

    databaseServer = OServerMain.create(true);
    databaseServer.startup(cfg);

    databaseServer.activate();
```

Comment: Hi Knut, 
it might be useful to you look at the following links
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/vRlJq28fh_8
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/5NCen4Zxfjs

Comment: Yes, I see. But I also tried with 2.2 beta, and I get the same error then. Any idea about configuring the server to use both autodeploy and hotalignment?

Comment: what is the type of your database? plocal?

Comment: Yes, the database servers are started using "plocal:./databases/test" as storage. We are running the servers embedded, using OServerMain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I have found a solution to this problem ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278865/how-to-setup-embedded-master-master-replication-with-orientdb))

I added these two lines before creating the server the server:

```
    String orientdbHome = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    System.setProperty("ORIENTDB_HOME", orientdbHome);
```

So the server is started like this:

```
    String orientdbHome = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    System.setProperty("ORIENTDB_HOME", orientdbHome);

    databaseServer = OServerMain.create(true);
    databaseServer.startup(cfg);

    databaseServer.activate();
```

And now there is no problem when starting node 2.

I think this information is missing from [this page](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Embedded-Server.html) from the documentation.

Comment: Interesting find, btw if you go to that page on the wiki an scroll up, there is an "edit this page" link in which you can add it to the docs, it will automatically create a pull request for the changes. You'll need a github account to do that.

Comment: I will propose to add a section explaining that this property should be set, and how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use hotAligment, it is seriously broken. It will be fixed in 2.2

See for example
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/2270
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5455

For now, adding and re-adding a node to a distributed setup needs to do a full sync of the database.

Comment: OK, I see. But when I try to use OrientDB 2.2.0-beta, I still get the same error. Any idea how to configure the database so I can use both hotalignment and autodeploy with 2.2?

Comment: OK, but the problem is the same as when using 2.1, so I don't think it's because 2.2

Comment: Ok, can you show the way you are starting the database? Share your embedded code?